# Переходы между экранами - Activity или XML?

Tags: android, activity

Не могу разобраться, как перейти на другое xml или обязательно создавать Activity для этого? И при каждом переходе на другое окно придется создавать Activity или есть другой способ!?

Comment: Ваш вопрос раскрывается в любом цикле уроков по программированию под Android. Почитайте/посмотрите их, и все станет ясно.

Comment: @weyners, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Создаёте 2 `Activity` (не забудьте указать новую активити в `manifest.xml`) и для каждого свой `layout`.

Переход из одной активити в другую осуществляется вот так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
```

или

`Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActvity.this, SecondActivity.class)`;

Так же можно использовать [фрагменты](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php).
Вот [где можно научиться](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php) делать переходы между экранами.

Answer (score 0):

Activity это и есть "окно" со своим жизненным циклом, можно использовать фрагменты.